# How to transport a derived object as a base object when the contract specifies an interface

Tags: wcf, datacontract

If a `[ServiceContract] [OperationContract]` specifies a return value that is an interface (`IInterface`) then I can return a Base object (`Base : IInterface`) or a Derived object (`Derived : Base`) using ServerKnownType attribute on the server interface.

If however I need to transport the Derived object as Base object (because Derived adds server side functionality I dont need client side) then Im stuck.
The `[DataContract(Name = "Base")]` on the Derived class trick (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402278/wcf-returning-a-derived-object-for-a-contract-with-base-object-datacontractres)) does NOT work in this case (where the server method returns an interface) because we must declare the Derived object AND the Base object as a KnownTypes - and when the server comes to resolve the types to serialize it doesn't like having 2 different known types with the same data contract name - and will thrown and exception when resolving.
**How to tranport Derived as Base in this case?**

Comment: I intend to answer this question myself as I have a solution.  Other approaches welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can used the following DataContractResolver to extend the use of [DataContract(Name = "Base")] as attribute on Derived to specify it should serialize as Base to work in the case where the server interface method returns an Interface not a concrete base type.
To use it the Base must be declared as a KnownType (ServerKnownType) and the Derived must have the [DataContract(Name = "Base")] attribute but NOT be declared a KnownType.

```
    public class DeserializeAsBaseResolver : DataContractResolver {
        public static void Install(ServiceHost serviceHost) {

            SetSerializationBehavior(serviceHost, "MethodReturningIInterfac");
        }

        public static void SetSerializationBehavior(ServiceHost serviceHost, string contractMethodName) {
            ContractDescription cd = serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].Contract;
            OperationDescription myOperationDescription = cd.Operations.Find(contractMethodName);

            bool methodFound = (myOperationDescription != null);
            if (!methodFound) {
                string msg = string.Format("\"{0}\" not a valid method on {1}",
                                           contractMethodName, cd.ConfigurationName);
                throw new ArgumentException(msg);
            }

            DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerBehavior =
                myOperationDescription.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
            if (serializerBehavior == null) {
                serializerBehavior = new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(myOperationDescription);
                myOperationDescription.Behaviors.Add(serializerBehavior);
            }
            serializerBehavior.DataContractResolver = new DeserializeAsBaseResolver();
        }

        public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType,
                                            DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver,
                                            out XmlDictionaryString typeName,
                                            out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace) {
            // Look for [DataContract(Name = "ClassType")] attribute and serialize as that
            // type if one is found:
            Type typeToResolveOn = type;
            DataContractAttribute dca = null;
            // .Net 4.0 and below code:
            object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataContractAttribute), false);
            foreach (object attibute in attributes) {
                if (attibute is DataContractAttribute) {
                    dca = attibute as DataContractAttribute;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // .Net 4.5 and above code:
            //dca = type.GetCustomAttribute<DataContractAttribute>();

            if (dca != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dca.Name)) {
                string modifiedAssemblyQualifiedName = string.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", type.Namespace, dca.Name, type.Assembly);
                Type serializeAsType = Type.GetType(modifiedAssemblyQualifiedName);
                if (serializeAsType != null)
                    typeToResolveOn = serializeAsType;
            }

            bool ret = knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(typeToResolveOn, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
            if (!ret && type != typeToResolveOn)
                ret = knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
            return ret;
        }

        public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace,
                                         Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver) {
            return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ?? declaredType;
        }
    }

}
```