# Serializing abstract class over WCF with subclasses in different assemblies

Tags: .net, wcf, abstract-class

We are using C# and .NET 4 to build an WCF-enabled application. We have a "parent" assembly that implements:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class A
{
  //...
}
```

Then, other "child" assemblies implement subclasses of `A`, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class B : A
{
  //...
}
```

In another assembly we have some methods that we are trying to encapsulate as WCF services. Some of these methods have a return type of `A`.

Evidently, child assemblies need to include a reference to the parent assembly in order for derived classes to inherit from class `A`. The problem arises when WCF seems to demand that we add `KnownType` attributes to class `A` to list all its potential subclasses; this would need that the parent assembly where `A` resides had references to the child assemblies, which would create circular dependencies.

Is there any other way around this? Does WCF really need to know the types of all the potential concrete classes of an abstract class that is being used as a return type? Thank you.

**EDIT**. We have tried the approach based on [KnownTypeAttribute.MethodName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.methodname(v=vs.100).aspx), as suggested by some comments. This would allow us to dynamically load the assemblies where the subclasses reside and return the subclasses to WCF on demand. It works when class `A` is used as a return type, but it doesn't work when it is used as a method parameter; we keep obtaining a "type not expected" WCF error. We'll keep trying approaches.

Comment: You may look at the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329464/wcf-probem-with-serializing-inherited-types

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140920/how-to-serialize-a-derived-type-as-its-base-type-with-wcf also interesting. This should help you. I have not tried, but seems it works.

Comment: @Kangkan: Thank you, sounds interesting.

Comment: Update here once you follow one of these and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the known types when you construct the Serializer which might get you around this issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344259.aspx

Comment: We are not constructing a DataContractSerializer by hand. Also, and as far as I can see from the link you provide, we would still need to provide a list of known types, so we would still have the circular dependency problem.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I did see that you are using WCF. You might have to put the different classes into the same assembly then, im not sure if there is a way around it? It will be interesting to see if Kangkan`s answer works